# regex capture if not in a certain pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match numbers that ends with `'` and are not in the pattern `\d+\s*/\s*\d+'`

```
x1 = "Better: 6 ' only"
x2 = """Better stain 15/16" 11/12\'"""
x3 = "14 / 16' 5' only"
x4 = "35' 14/15' better"
lst = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
```

expected output

```
x1 -> 6
x2 -> None
x3 -> 5
x4 -> 35
```

this is what I have so far `(?<!\d/)(\d+\s*\')`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Best regex trick ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick), see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/GWt1LX). There are other approaches if you can use PyPi regex library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One of the best tricks I've learned, thanks a lot for sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a capture group with an alternation.

The match before the pipe gets out of the way what you don't want to match, then after the pipe you can capture what you want to keep, which in this case is 1 or more digits followed by `'`

```
\d+\s*/\s*\d+'|(\d+)\s*'
```

- `\d+\s*/\s*\d+'`
- `|` Or
- `(\d+)\s*'` Capture 1+ digits in group 1 followed by optional whitespace chars and `'`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hkqJ7V/1)

Comment: please explain why this works

Comment: @User19 I am writing an explanation now..1 sec